# Add only chapter name in small letters and page number in header

Tags: header-footer, chapters, page-numbering

I'm using `\documentclass[pdftex,10pt,b5paper,twoside]{book}`.

And I want the header to contain only the chapter name in small letters and the page namer. 
And if possible, having the chapter name on the inner side and the page and the number on the outer side.

I'm new at LaTeX and I'm struggling to figure out the right way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the job:

```
\documentclass[pdftex,10pt,b5paper,twoside]{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[automark,markcase=lower]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\KOMAoptions{headsepline=0.2pt }
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\renewcommand\chaptermarkformat{~}
\automark[chapter]{chapter}

\begin{document}
\chapter{ch 1}
\section{Sec 1.1}
\lipsum[1-10]
\chapter{Ch 2}
\section{Sec 2.1}
\lipsum[11-20]
\end{document}
```

The [KOMA](https://ctan.org/pkg/koma-script?lang=en) skript is very helpful to achieve such things.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help, it worked!

Comment: You're welcome. Please upvote and accept my answer then :)

Comment: I have upvoted, but do not have enough reputations yet to make them visible. I also have a problem. The script work, but I also get this error message: Package scrlayer Error: cannot define `\cfoot' and Package scrlayer Error: cannot define `\chead'. I dont understand why

Comment: But you can still accept the answer (check mark underneath) if you like my answer. Have you changed anything? Because my example doesn't use `\cfoot` or `\chead`